# Match and replace many values in data.table

Tags: r, replace, data.table

I have a dataset with many misnamed entries. I created a two column .csv that includes the old (incorrect) names in one column and the corresponding new (correct) names in the second column. Now I need to tell R to replace every old name in the data with the correct name.

```
testData = data.table(oldName = c("Nu York", "Was DC", "Buston",  "Nu York"))
replacements = data.table(oldName = c("Buston", "Nu York", "Was DC"), 
    newName = c("Boston", "New York", "Washington DC"))

    # The next line fails.
holder = replace(testData, testData[, oldName]==replacements[, oldName], 
    replacements[, newName]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how I'd do that replacement:

```
setkey(testData, oldName)
setkey(replacements, oldName)

testData[replacements, oldName := newName]
testData
#         oldName
#1:        Boston
#2:      New York
#3:      New York
#4: Washington DC
```

You can add an index if you like the original order and put it back in original order at the end.

Comment: For future reference, I added an id column and then sorted with `testData[order(rank(id))]`

Comment: @DTRM this is how I'd do it: `testData[, id := .I]`, then the above operations, and finally `setkey(testData, id)`.

Comment: Thanks. The help file says "`.I` is an integer vector length." Could you give a less opaque (than the data.table help file) description of what `.I` is doing?

Comment: @DTRM `.I` is simply the vector `1:nrow(your_dt)` (just made more efficient internally)

Answer (score 5):

I reached here looking for a solution and managed to tweak it to my requirement. **If original order needs to be maintained** then don't use `setkey`. I've added mutually exclusive rows on both tables for a better test.

```
library(data.table)

testData = data.table(
  city = c("Nu York", "Was DC", "Buston",  "Nu York", "Alabama")
)
```

If the join by column name in lookup table is **same**:

```
replacements = data.table(
  city = c("Buston", "Nu York", "Was DC", "tstDummy"), 
  city_newName = c("Boston", "New York", "Washington DC", "Test Dummy")
)

testData[replacements, city := city_newName, on=.(city)][]
```

If the join by column name in lookup table is **different**:

```
replacements = data.table(
  city_oldName = c("Buston", "Nu York", "Was DC", "tstDummy"), 
  city_newName = c("Boston", "New York", "Washington DC", "Test Dummy")
)

testData[replacements, city := city_newName, on=.(city = city_oldName)][]
```

Either way, `testData` will be changed to:

```
            city
1:      New York
2: Washington DC
3:        Boston
4:      New York
5:       Alabama
```

No keys are made and original order is retained.